# Caching objects built with multiple parameters

Tags: java, caching, dictionary, factory

I have a factory that creates objects of class **MyClass**, returning already generated ones when they exist. As I have the creation method (**getOrCreateMyClass**) taking multiple parameters, which is the best way to use a Map to store and retrieve the objects?

My current solution is the following, but it doesn't sound too clear to me.
I use the hashCode method (slightly modified) of class MyClass to build an int based on the parameters of class MyClass, and I use it as the key of the Map.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyClassFactory {

    static Map<Integer, MyClass> cache = new HashMap<Integer, MyClass>();

    private static class MyClass {
        private String s;
        private int i;

        public MyClass(String s, int i) {
        }

        public static int getHashCode(String s, int i) {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + i;
            result = prime * result + ((s == null) ? 0 : s.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return getHashCode(this.s, this.i);
        }

    }


    public static MyClass getOrCreateMyClass(String s, int i) {
        int hashCode =  MyClass.getHashCode(s, i);
        MyClass a = cache.get(hashCode);
        if (a == null) {
            a = new MyClass(s, i);
             cache.put(hashCode , a);

        } 
        return a;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Why don't you like it?

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem too much object oriented to me, and I'm currently having an unknown bug with a factory like this, but maybe the problem is not in that code...

Comment: sorry, I forgot a line!! (this was example code), fixing cache.put

Comment: If `getOrCreateMyClass` is going to be the method through which all clients get instances of `MyClass`, I'd recommend giving it a simpler name like just `get`... it probably doesn't need so much information about how it works in its name. You'll probably want its Javadoc to mention that it always returns the same instance for a given pair of inputs of course.

Comment: It is called flyweight pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using the hashcode as the key in your map. A class's hashcode is not intended to necessarily guarantee that it will not be the same for any two non-equal instances of that class. Indeed, your hashcode method could definitely produce the same hashcode for two non-equal instances. You do *need* to implement `equals` on `MyClass` to check that two instances of `MyClass` are equal based on the equality of the `String` and `int` they contain. I'd also recommend making the `s` and `i` fields `final` to provide a stronger guarantee of the immutability of each `MyClass` instance if you're going to be using it this way.

Beyond that, I think what you actually want here is an *interner*.... that is, something to guarantee that you'll only ever store at most 1 instance of a given `MyClass` in memory at a time. The correct solution to this is a `Map<MyClass, MyClass>`... more specifically a `ConcurrentMap<MyClass, MyClass>` if there's any chance of `getOrCreateMyClass` being called from multiple threads. Now, you do need to create a new instance of `MyClass` in order to check the cache when using this approach, but that's inevitable really... and it's not a big deal because `MyClass` is easy to create.

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) has something that does all the work for you here: its [Interner](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html) interface and corresponding [Interners](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html) factory/utility class. Here's how you might use it to implement `getOrCreateMyClass`:

```
private static final Interner<MyClass> interner = Interners.newStrongInterner();

public static MyClass getOrCreateMyClass(String s, int i) {
  return interner.intern(new MyClass(s, i));
}
```

Note that using a strong interner will, like your example code, keep each `MyClass` it holds in memory as long as the interner is in memory, regardless of whether anything else in the program has a reference to a given instance. If you use `newWeakInterner` instead, when there isn't anything elsewhere in your program using a given `MyClass` instance, that instance will be eligible for garbage collection, helping you not waste memory with instances you don't need around.

If you choose to do this yourself, you'll want to use a `ConcurrentMap` cache and use `putIfAbsent`. You can take a look at the implementation of Guava's strong interner for reference I imagine... the weak reference approach is much more complicated though.

Comment: +1: If MyClass is indeed just as cheap to create as a Pair, and if the OP is willing to add Guava as a dependency, this certainly does sound like the better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your `getOrCreateMyClass` doesn't seem to add to the cache if it creates.

I think this will also not perform correctly when hashcodes collide.  Identical hashcodes do not imply equal objects.  This could be the source of the bug you mentioned in a comment.

You might consider creating a generic `Pair` class with actual `equals` and `hashCode` methods and using `Pair<String, Integer>` class as the map key for your cache.

**Edit:**

The issue of extra memory consumption by storing both a `Pair<String, Integer>` key and a `MyClass` value might be best dealt with by making the `Pair<String, Integer>` into a field of `MyClass` and thereby having only one reference to this object.

With all of this though, you might have to worry about threading issues that don't seem to be addressed yet, and which could be another source of bugs.

And whether it is actually a good idea at all depends on whether the creation of `MyClass` is much more expensive than the creation of the map key.

**Another Edit:**

ColinD's answer is also reasonable (and I've upvoted it), as long as the construction of `MyClass` is not expensive.

Another approach that might be worth consideration is to use a nested map `Map<String, Map<Integer, MyClass>>`, which would require a two-stage lookup and complicate the cache updating a bit.

Comment: +1 for the collision remark.
I'd advise against using the Pair as a key, since you'll be retaining *two* references to each object in MyClass, making the cache even more memory consuming.

Comment: I have to create thousands of MyClass objects, so I was hoping to avoid creating new Pair key objects each time. The collision remark is really interesting

Comment: I'm not thrilled by the effect on memory consumption either.  I can't think of an alternative that much reduces the memory consumption without reintroduce the hashcode collision risk though.

Comment: I absolutely need to cache these objects, as only one object built with given parameter values must exists at the same time.
I like the idea of the internal state inside an object, it's the Memento pattern if I'm not wrong